# Not receiving realtime updates at all from Facebook

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook

I've setup my server to receive realtime updates from facebook, I've gone through the authentication to get the token etc, registered the callback url... and I've not received a single notice since the authentication GET request.

When I `GET graph.facebook.com/APP-ID/subscriptions` I receive...

```
data: [
{
  object: "user",
  callback_url: "REDACTED-VAID-URL",
  fields: [
    "activities",
    "books",
    "checkins",
    "events",
    "feed",
    "friends",
    "interests",
    "likes",
    "location",
    "movies",
    "music",
    "television"
  ],
  active: true
}
]
```

So as far as I can tell the realtime notification is setup correctly.
When I send my own POST to the callback URL the server emails me the POST details every time, but I've never received this after a facebook update, so I'm pretty sure it's just not hitting the URL.
I've several users authenticated with the app, we've all tried various things on facebook to try and trigger it (status update, post, like etc). I can pull in their feed etc from the normal rest API.

There must be something I'm just missing here, what else do I need to do to get this to work?!

Comment: Im exactly as far as you have gotten on this one. I have managed to set up a subscription correctly, but I dont recieve any notifications what so ever.. Upvoted!

Comment: Not really an answer, but, in response to Alexander's ping of me about this and related issues:  I'm afraid I don't have much to offer.  Assuming that your app up on Facebook is properly configured (which it seems to be, since you're getting proper subscription information), my only thought is to make sure that the hits from Facebook are able to get through your network/firewall/etc/ to your server.  Are other hits from Facebook showing up?  Have you tried POSTing to the callback url from some place outside your immediate network?  Sorry I can't be more help...

Comment: I've actually been able to test that I can receive the notifications from facebooks servers, I found the option to make test users and I receive the notifications when I post content as a test user.
I have received the occasional notification from real users 'liking' pages on facebook, however this has only happened occasionally for some users, not all, and I've never received one for a user posting content. This must be an issue at facebooks end, I've opened a but report but not received any feedback in more than a week.

Answer (score 3):

For those using PHP...

Facebook's realtime POST data won't come in or be recognizable via the normal $_POST array in PHP.  You can use the following to get the raw JSON making up the request to your server:

```
$json = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

You can then convert this into an array simply by:

```
$realtime = json_decode($json, true);
```

It's too bad, however, that the data Facebook gives you in these requests is mostly worthless :-/

Comment: +1 for the tip about getting the POST data. Also, the data Facebook gives you isn't worthless at all. They tell you what object had a change and then it's up to you to do another call to the graph to get the updated data.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was accepting GET requests but wasn't accepting POST requests on the callback URL.